# Align chat bubble to the left of the RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a chat app and I have everything set to go, the problem is, when I'm displaying my text in the RecyclerView, the `friend` chat bubble aligns like the text the user sends. How can I align it to the left of the recyclerview?
I have 2 different layots, one for each bubble, and one recyclerview adapter.

This is a photo explaining my problem:

[image]

And here is the `own_message.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    android:paddingStart="60dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/own_message_body"
        style="@style/ChatBubble"
        android:background="@drawable/own_message"
        tools:text="This is my own message, hope it is okay.">
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `others_message.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="60dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/others_message_body"
        style="@style/ChatBubble"
        android:background="@drawable/others_message"
        tools:text="Hey! I am a stranger, i'm chatting with you right now! :)" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/others_message_body"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/others_message_body"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/others_message_body"
        android:contentDescription="@string/user_avatar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user_avatar">

    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And, if it is needed, this is where I call my adapter:

```
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
                binding.recyclerViewChat.layoutManager = layoutManager
                binding.recyclerViewChat.setHasFixedSize(true)
                val adapter = ChatAdapter(messages)
                binding.recyclerViewChat.adapter = adapter
```

How can I align the friends chat bubbles to the left of the adapter?

Comment: Can you please share your `@style/ChatBubble`. In addition, I believe the issue is with your `ImageView` and `TextView` for the `others_message.xml`. Your layout should be aligned to the start. Therefore, replace `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/others_message_body"` with `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"`. Then, give the `ImageView` an `id`, such as `imageViewId`, and add to TextView `android:layout_alignEnd="@id/imageViewId"`

Comment: You got it! Would you like to make that an answer so I can green check it?

Comment: Yes sir, just give me a moment :D <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your layouts are aligned to the right. You want the `others_message.xml` to be aligned to the left.

You want your `ImageView` to be aligned to the `start` of the `parent`. And then, you want the `TextView` to be aligned to the `end` of that `ImageView`.

Therefore, you're gonna want to do the following:

1. Replace `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/others_message_body"` with `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"` in the `ImageView`
2. Give the `ImageView` an `id`, such as `android:id="@+id/imageViewId"`
3. Align the `TextView` to the end of the `ImageView` by adding `android:layout_alignEnd="@id/imageViewId"`

The final result of `others_message.xml` should look something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="60dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/others_message_body"
        style="@style/ChatBubble"
        android:background="@drawable/others_message"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/imageViewId"
        tools:text="Hey! I am a stranger, i'm chatting with you right now! :)" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewId"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/others_message_body"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/others_message_body"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/user_avatar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user_avatar">

    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```